# Abstract Class/Method Implementation

Tags: java, methods, abstract-class, abstract

I'm supposed to design a `BankAcct`  class with an abstract method `computeIntt()`.  Save and Time are kinds of BankAcct. The problem is I can't implement the displaying of the Interest and the New balance

Here's my current codes:

```
public abstract class BankAcct 
{
    private int accountNumber;
    private String accountName;
    private double bal;

    public BankAcct(int act, String name, double m)
    {
        accountNumber = act;
        accountName = name;
        bal = m;
    }

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return bal;
    }

    public String getAccountName()
    {
        return accountName;
    }

    public int getAccountNumber()
    {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void deposit(double m)
    {
            bal+=m;
    }

    public void withdraw(double m)
    {
        bal-=m;
    }

    public abstract double computeInt();
}
```

---

```
public class Save extends BankAcct 
{
    public Save(int act, String name, double m)
    {
        super(act, name, m);
    }

    int act;
    String name="";
    double m;

    public double computeInt()
    {
        return m * 0.0025;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Time extends BankAcct 
{
    public Time(int act, String name, double m)
    {
        super(act, name, m);
    }

    int act;
    String name="";
    double m;

    public double computeInt()
    {
        return m * 0.033;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class MainPr 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BankAcct sav = new Savings(1234, "ABC", 10000);
        BankAcct td = new TimeDeposit(9876, "DEF", 20000);

        // display the current balance
    
        System.out.println(sav.getAccountName() + " with account number " +
                    sav.getAccountNumber() + " has a balance of " +
                    sav.getBalance());
    
        System.out.println(td.getAccountName() + " with account number " +
            td.getAccountNumber() + " has a balance of " +
            td.getBalance());
    
        // deposit money
    
        sav.withdraw(5000.0);
    
        // display current value with its interest
    
        System.out.println("\n" + sav.getAccountName() + " with account number " +
            sav.getAccountNumber() + " earned an interest of " +
            sav.computeInt());
    
        System.out.println(sav.getAccountName() + " with account number " +
            sav.getAccountNumber() + " has a NEW BALANCE of " +
            sav.getBalance());
    
        td.deposit(2000.0);
    
        System.out.println("\n" + td.getAccountName() + " with account number " +
            td.getAccountNumber() + " earned an interest of " +
            td.computeInt());
    
        System.out.println(td.getAccountName() + " with account number " +
            td.getAccountNumber() + " has a NEW BALANCE of " +
            td.getBalance());
    }
}
```

MainPr that will instantiate two objects for the following data:
Save has account number of 1234; account name of ABC; balance of 10,000.
Time has account number of 9876; account name DEF; balance of 20,000.

This should be the output: CORRECT ONE

> ABC with account number 1234 has a balance of 10000.0
>
> DEF with account number 9876 has a balance of 20000.0
>
> ABC with account number 1234 earned interest 25.0
>
> ABC with account number 1234 has a NEW balance of 5025.0
>
> DEF with account number 9876 earned interest 660.0
>
> DEF with account number 9876 has a NEW balance of 22660.0

but my program produces the incorrect output:

> ABC with account number 1234 has a balance of 10000.0
>
> DEF with account number 9876 has a balance of 20000.0
>
> ABC with account number 1234 earned interest 0.0
>
> ABC with account number 1234 has a NEW balance of 5000.0
>
> DEF with account number 9876 earned interest 0.0
>
> DEF with account number 9876 has a NEW balance of 22000.0

In this case, in Save the interest rate is 0.25% while the interest in time is 3.3% The balance depends whether it is deposit or withdraw.

Kindly help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance variables `m` are always `0` (never initialized) in your subclasses, but they look like they are set to the `bal` in your `BankAcct` class. Wouldn't this be appropriate for your `computerInterest` method in `TimeDeposit`:

```
public double computeInterest() {
    return getBalance() * 0.033;
}
```

A similar fix should be provided in the other subclass or at least initialize your `m` variables. On a related note, your subclasses don't need to define `act` or `name` since your superclass `BankAcct` has it defined and stored already.

Also, your `computerInterest` isn't modifying your balance, which your program seems to expect. If that's the case, this might be more appropriate:

```
public double computeInterest() {
    double interest = getBalance() * 0.033;
    deposit(interest);
    return interest;
}
```

Comment: So I'm going to delete the "public TimeDeposit(int act, String name, double m)" and the declaration part?

Comment: Nope, that's the constructor and still needed. That's what is passing the variables to the superclass. These three lines are unnecessary though: `int act; String name=""; double m;`

Comment: Kindly help me with my formulas. Something's wrong with it, it still doesn't produce the good output

Comment: How can i correctly display the NEW BALANCE? I am particularly having problem in displaying the NEW BAL of Savings. It should be 5025.0 but it displays 4975.0

Comment: If you use the second `computeInterest` I posted, things should work. You'll have to calculate the interest on the savings before withdrawing, though, to get the correct NEW BALANCE on your savings.